# Vertical squishing of images on iPhone 5C under iOS 7 using HTML5 canvas in Safari

Tags: iphone, ios, html

I have developed a mobile web application which allows the user to take a picture with their mobile device camera and then displays it on an HTML5 canvas.  When running this web application on an iPhone 5C under iOS 7, the image is severely vertically squished, so that it appears distorted and takes up approximately 20% of the canvas instead of taking 100% as intended.

This may be related to Safari image subsampling, which also caused vertical squishing in earlier versions of iOS and on other devices, although not nearly as bad as what is being seen in the above issue.  A jquery plugin named megapix-image.js was created to address this issue and it works on iPhone4 and iPad running iOS 6 to correct this vertical squishing so the image appears correctly.  megapix-image.js appears not to be compatible with iPhone 5/iOS 7 (it will not convert the image file).

Something to note is that iOS 7 completely corrected the vertical squishing issue seen on iPhone 4, but it has apparently made the problem much worse on iPhone 5/5C.

Is there a solution to this issue?

Solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/megapix-image.js"></script> 
<script>

var mpImg = new MegaPixImage(file);
var mpImg.render(srcImage, {maxWidth: 960, maxHeight: 960});
</script>
```

where file is the file from the fileInput control and srcImage is the corrected image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that megapixel-image.js does work with iPhone 5 and iOS 7.  I found I was calling some parameters incorrectly.  The plug-in corrects the vertical squishing issue.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue.
Can you share your solution?

Comment: Solution posted above, Ashit.  Feel free to ask me any questions about it.

Comment: Thanks Obi Wan :) . I finally did it on server side (using PHP).